# In Python Only Xml Values are storing after renaming text file to Xml file instead of whole XML content

Tags: python, xml, file

I have downloaded xml contents in Excel . In each excel sheet having multiple rows with one column. Each column is a XML content.

So I have iterated through it tried to save as an XML file(one XML file per column). But only Values are automatically getting parsed and stored instead of whole XML structure.

So I have stored as a txt file . So now XML content is stored as a text file.

When tried to rename from txt to XML, same behaviour continues. Please assist.

Below is the input & output.
Input as a text file :

```
 <product>
    <title>TestProduct</title>
    <Specifications>
      <item name="Specifications1">Test</item>
      <item name="Specifications2">Hello World</item>
    </Specifications>
    <body>
      <item name="Color">Black</item>
    </body>
 </product>
```

Output after Rename to xml file:
TestProduct Test Hello World Black

```
import xlrd
import os
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET
        ExcelFileName= 'pythonwork.xlsx'
        workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(ExcelFileName)
        worksheet = workbook.sheet_by_name("sheet1")
        num_rows = worksheet.nrows
        num_cols = worksheet.ncols
        result_data = []
        x = 0
            for curr_row in range(0, num_rows, 1):
                row_data = []
                for curr_col in range(0, num_cols, 1):
                    data = worksheet.cell_value(curr_row, curr_col)
                    #print(curr_row)
                    if type(data)  is str:
            #print(type(data))
                        if data.find("xml version") > 0:
                            #print(data)
                            #tree = ET.XML(data)
                            x = x + 1
                            filename = 'pax_gen_' + str(x) +'.txt'
                            file = open(filename, "w") 
                            file.write(data)
                            file.close()
                            my_file = filename
                            base = os.path.splitext(my_file)[0]
                            os.rename(my_file, base + '.xml')
```

Also tried the below and getting error

```
formatedXML = minidom.parseString(ET.tostring(root)).toprettyxml(indent=" ",encoding='utf-8').strip()
```

ExpatError: not well-formed (invalid token): line 1, column 16

Comment: There is no text file ..

Comment: Hi, Actually the xml content stored in a .txt file. I have stored in txt file because when tryingto save in .xml only attribute values are getting saved

Comment: so you have this xml `<product>...</product>` - what is the data you want to extract from it?

Comment: The same payload i need to save as filename.xml file. now its in filename.txt file

Comment: Not change to be made inthe file content

Comment: so you need to rename x.txt to x.xml? is that your question?

Comment: Ofcourse that is the need. when i tried only values are saving

Comment: What about `os.rename()` ? see https://careerkarma.com/blog/python-rename-file/#:~:text=To%20rename%20a%20file%20using,by%20the%20new%20file%20name.

Comment: Hi @balderman, I have tried that already but only XML attribute values are getting saved on renaming nto the full content. I have mentioned that in the initial description and code snippet as well

Comment: Text file as <product>
    <title>TestProduct</title>
    <Specifications>
      <item name="Specifications1">Test</item>
      <item name="Specifications2">Hello World</item>
    </Specifications>
    <body>
      <item name="Color">Black</item>
    </body>
 </product>     .. but when renamed to XML only "TestProduct Test Hello World Black" is the content in file

Comment: hI @balderman, The issue got resolved. Actually the issue is with Jupyter notebook. The same code I have ran in Spyder IDE and its creating the XML successfully. Some issue in Jupyter notebook on my Pc. Will check that. Thanks for your tiem and support